# Comprehensive google map plugin for wordpress not working

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, wordpress

I am working with Wordpress 3.8 and use comprehensive google map plugin 9.0.19 but it is not showing map on linked page. It just showing error in console:

```
ReferenceError: CGMPGlobal is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

<script type='text/javascript'>CGMPGlobal.language = 'en';</script>
```

Please help me That what to do!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a new key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

You should then load Google Maps with your key:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

Comment: where i have to put generated API key i am so confused at this time please take me out from this problem.Now i have new API key but little bit confused that where i put this key.